# TSQL Job executes based on a logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I need to execute a job that, in turn, executes an SSIS package in catalog. The job should execute when the Status of the package is ready. Where can i write the condition that `If Status='Ready` then execute the job.

Comment: Where are you getting this status from?  I don't see 'Ready' in [this list of SSIS package statuses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345164.aspx).

Comment: The question is a little unclear. What are you trying to do? Set up a sort of trigger to dynamically start a job with a SSIS job step? What exactly do you mean with "_when the Status of the package is ready_"?

Comment: Where are you executing the SQL Agent Job from? is it from an SSIS package or are you placing the condition in one of the steps of the job?